# Is there an std function that only returns its parameter?

Tags: c++, stl

That should be trivial to implement, something like

```
template<typename T>
T & as_is(T & t) { return t; }
```

Still, I'd like not to have to write it (:

I did not find such a thing on [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com).

For those who will ask "what are you trying to do", here is the thing. I have a class that builds ascii tables, with nice padding and everything. I'll spare the details. The important thing is that it stores strings (so it's able to calculate how much to pad). I want to implement a sort function and be able to tell the class to use the column as a certain type. If I want to sort by a column of ints (which, again, are internally strings), i'd pass `atoi`. If sorting strings, I want to pass `as_is`, or the stl equivalent, if any.

Comment: Maybe `std::forward<T&>` satisfies those requirements?

Comment: @Kerrek: That's a good one, although it requires you to spell the template arguments out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a template as though it were a function, so neither std::forward nor your hypothetical nonstd::identity function will work as-is (as it were). You'd need to explicitly set the target type of the transform:

```
table.SortColumnUsing(3, nonstd::identity<std::string>);
```

That seems a bit ugly to me, because the type in the template specialization is a feature of the internal implementation of table, rather than having anything to do with the type I'm expecting the table to serialize into for the purposes of sorting. Or perhaps you don't really store the columns as std::string.

How does atoi work as a type descriptor? atoi expects a char*, not a std::string, and I didn't think you could implicitly convert `int(const char*)` into `int(const std::string&)`. Even if you could do that, what type do you use which can store both an `int(const std::string&)` and a `Banana(const std string&)`. Perhaps I don't fully understand the context of your question, or alternatively you have some C++ tricks up your sleeve which I'd love to learn.

My inclination would be to pass a comparison function rather than a conversion function. That would result in a single constant function type, maybe `bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)`. That might also make it simpler to implement eg. case-insensitive or locale-specific string comparison for particular columns, or other UI-convenient sorting hacks (like putting folders at the top of the list: first check if only one of the strings has a trailing /, otherwise use standard comparison.) That doesn't really solve the specialization issue, though; for the `std::string` case, you still end up with `std::less<std::string>` (which at least exists.)

Not a great answer, I know... but it was too long for a comment.

Comment: This is a good answer, as it goes after the cause, not the problem. Passing a conversion function to sort in "integral order" sounds bad as is, so +1 on suggesting a comparision function.

Comment: I'm actually passing a comparison function to the current sort function. I want(ed) to get rid of it because of the verbosity of the construct. That said, I forgot that I still have to `.c_str()` the strings in the functor's `atoi`, which would prevent passing it as-is to the sort function, thus breaking the example.

Answer (score 3):

Why not overload the function and not pass anything?

Btw, if you're working with MSVC, they have the `identity` class template, which has an overloaded `operator()` that returns the input. So in theory, you could pass `std::identity<std::string>()`, but I'd say, just build your own `identity` function.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like identity is not MS specific: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/identity.html http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00497.html

Comment: Overloading would mean duplicating some code. To avoid duplication, the overload without param would call the version with param, giving identity. This would be providing convenience methods, adding complexity while not adding any feature.

Comment: @Gabriel it was in an older draft of the latest standard but was dropped. You won't find it on GCC 4.6.